# How to debug specific files in Winforms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, debugging

[image]

I am trying to debug Exercise2_2.cs file but when I hit f5, Visual Studio always debug Exercise2_1.cs only. In this case what should I do in order to get VS to run Exercise2_2.cs thanks.

Comment: How does Program.cs look like?

Comment: You don't debug files. You debug the project. You run the project in the debugger and, if you want to debug code in a specific file, you need to use the app such that that code gets executed.

Comment: @jmcilhinney which means I need to create a new project every time I need to debug a new exercise? Aren't there a way just to select and run my Winform in Exercise_2.2?

Comment: I don't know exactly how your exercises are structured but it might be the most appropriate thing to create a separate project for each. If not, it's probably just a matter for changing a line of code in the `Main` method to execute code you want. Again, you're not debugging files. It's quite possible to execute some code from both files but not all from either in the same debugging session. You just need to write code to do what you actually want to do. You might even have code in the `Main` method that lets you specify one of multiple execution paths when you run the app. It's up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of pressing F5 (Run Solution), assuming you have the C# KeyBindings press F10 and F11 to step through the code and find the line of code that is instantiating Exercise2_1.

It would be even simpler to do a find in the code base for "Exercise2_1" and change it to  Exercise2_2.

Note the class names may be different to the file names, so open the c# files and confirm they're called Exercise2_1 and Exercise2_2.

Comment: thanks for the information. I have tested the way you mentioned above. I would like to share more here for those who face the same problem as I do. Press f10 and visual studio will open Program.cs tab so you can change the Application.Run(new Exercise2_2()) and by default it is new Exercise2_1()